# How to create a horizontal table in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have a physical journaling setup that I want to move to Emacs/org-mode for better integration with the rest of my note-taking. I have a set of questions that I rate myself on. On paper, I was using one row for each question and one column for every day (mostly because my questions are relatively long, and I can fit everything on one page this way). See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cortex/comments/de6gnz/on_my_weekly_sunday_evening_review_i_thought_id/) for an example of what I mean.

Is there a way to do something similar in org-mode/Emacs? I tried doing this with tables, but I couldn't figure out how to expand the tables horizontally instead of vertically.

I tried searching for something like "org table by row", "vertical table org-mode" or "transpose org table" but haven't found what I was looking for.

Comment: Org mode adds an `Org` menu and a `Table` menu to the menubar at the top (unless you have disabled that, but you shouldn't). Under the `Table` menu there is a `Column` and a `Row` submenu. You can use those to expand the table at will. But there are other useful operations there. Going through the menus is a good way to learn about additional capabilities.

Comment: @NIckD Interesting. I am using Doom which disables the menu by default. I'll enable it to find out whether I find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, what do you mean by 'expand' the table horizontally?

Maybe this isn't what you meant, but you can add a column with `M-S-right`. If this is wrong maybe you could clarify? Nice journaling!

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!

Comment: @sonofhypnos If an answer solves your problem, you can give it an upvote and click the checkmark icon. That will mark the question as solved, so it doesn't show up in the 'questions needing answers' queue.